# How to make Firefox look more like the current GTK theme?

Tags: firefox, themes, thunderbird

AFAIK this has always been an issue with Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird. They always have a number of elements that don't align with the current theme, which can be fixed by the user creating and/or modifying "...`/<profile_dir>/chrome/userChrome.css`".

For instance, I add the following block (changing color values  according to the GTK current theme) in order to make Thunderbir sidebar  look like other sidebars:

```
#folderTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(even) {
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    background-color: #eff0f1 !important;
}

#folderTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(odd) {
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    background-color: #eff0f1 !important;
}

#folderTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    background-color: #3daee9 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

#folderTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-row(hover) {
border: 1px solid transparent !important;
background-color: #3daee9 !important;
}

#folderTree > treechildren::-moz-tree-line {
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

However, I need a little help in changing hover background color in menus and toolbars (both Firefox and Thunderbird) as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

The light grey hover background color seen in the built-in menu of Firefox (and also the menu button, which is the same as other toolbar and bookmark bar buttons) should actully be light blue (like the border color of address bar).

How can I implement this?

Comment: Is this problem with Firefox evident with all your gtk3 themes?

Comment: @DKBose Yes! My system is Kubuntu 19.10, but I can see it's the same in Ubuntu 18.04, Linux Mint 19.3, etc. which not only have with different gtk3 themes but different DEs!

Comment: You're right. I see that as well. I initially thought differently because my colors matched my theme but that's because my theme is a dark one with a light grey highlight. A nice place to ask is https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/. I've gotten answers there in the past.

Comment: Same here. FF ignores system GTK3 theme set in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/`. The only way to force it respect it is to launch it with `GTK_THEME=My firefox-esr`. Other GTK3 app doesn't require that. Have you ever found a permanent solution?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Note that the behavior [has been changed in Firefox 89](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1707470). Another [change has been made in Firefox 90](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1710324) as well. Since Firefox 90, we could use the `widget.non-native-theme.gtk.scrollbar.*` settings in `about:config` to modify the scrollbar look.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
In my case, Firefox ESR 78 ignores system GTK3 theme set in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` as well as returned by:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

This is most noticeable by a vertical scrollbar on a long page having the default GTK3 Adwauta theme look. Other GTK3 app use the proper theme and doesn't have this issue.

The fix is to launch Firefox with the following command line:

```
GTK_THEME=My firefox-esr`
```

Or to make it permanent, you could add the following lime to your `~/.profile`:

```
export GTK_THEME=<Your theme name like Adwaita:dark>
```

Comment: I started Firefox from terminal with the command `GTK_THEME=Breeze firefox` but unfortunately I still get the highlight bgcolor light grey in the menu although Breeze has a blue one. :-(

Comment: @Sadi Breeze (as some other themes) has 2 variants: light and dark. If not explicitly specified, the light one is used usually. That's why I've demonstrated  how to specify a dark variant with `:dark` postfix in my answer. Try `GTK_THEME=Breeze:dark`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make any change either (firefox 87). I tried all possible combinations of Breeze/breeze:light/dark but I still got that grey highlight instead of blue. I wonder if it's your OS or Firefox (version) that makes difference??? I'm using KDE neon now as I'm too impatient to wait so long to enjoy the latest developments in KDE Plasma. ;-)

Comment: @Sadi Please take a look at the **UPDATE** I've added to my answer if it could help you. Just in case, I'm using a manualy modified GTK 3 theme, but it doesn't seem to be required. You could implement your own modifications by copying some standard GTK 3 theme and modifying `/usr/share/themes/<your-theme-name>/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file. Just search for the `* Scrollbars *` sections there.